# Google Sheets sort by ascending order

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

A1=30, B1=9, C1=35, D1=23

How can I make it so that I can sort A1:D1 in ascending order in a different row while such as A2:D2 while keeping A1:D1?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can use this on A2:

```
=transpose(sort(transpose(A1:D1),1,true))
```

`sort()` works only on columns so you have to use `transpose()` twice.

[image]

### Reference:

[transpose()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(SMALL(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A:D))))`

The key here is the `SEQUENCE` made of 1 row and as many columns as are in the range (with the default starting number and interval both being 1). This will give you the *n*th `SMALL`est numbers in the range for each of the numbers generated by the `SEQUENCE`.

If the number of columns will always be the same (e.g., 4 in your example), you could use this simplified version:

`=ArrayFormula(SMALL(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(1,4)))`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(FLATTEN(1:1),1,1))
```